# React specifying inline styles

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to specify inline styles for my react component something this way:

```
var style = {
    border-left: 1px solid #222,
    color: #FFFF,
    float: 'right',
    font-size: 14px
}

<div id="myDiv" style={style}> </div>
```

My linter keeps throwing me an error saying unexpected token on line 3 - that is border-left: 1px solid #222.

What am I doing wrong? Or how's the way to set styles?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of 4 Fs in #FFFF? Try #FFF

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string

You have multiple errors here it seems:

- First, the marked line is wrong, because `border-left` should be `borderLeft`
- `1px solid #222` should be in quotes I believe, as should every property value, i.e. color, font size
- `font-size`, the same as `border-left` should be `fontSize`
- you might also want to use const instead of var, if you use ES6

Reference here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object to a style property of HTML's element, keys should have upper camelCase and values must have a string type in an object. for example:-

```
var myStyle = {
    borderLeft: '1px solid #222',
    color: '#FFFF',
    float: 'right',
    fontSize: '14px'
}
<div id="myDiv" style={myStyle}></div>
```

Comment: [click here to more...](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)